# How can I display and refresh data in the terminal without continually appending to it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, stdout, ansi-escape

So when you `console.log` you're appending lines to stdout. I understand that much, but how do programs like *top* print to the console a continually refreshed view of data and then wipe that data when you kill it?

[image]

You can see when I kill *top* its data is no longer displayed. I can't scroll in my terminal window or anything to see it either, like most other scripts and programs I use.

How can I do this in node? I want to display some data and continually refresh it in place until the script is killed.

Comment: Try [blessed-contrib](https://github.com/yaronn/blessed-contrib) or [clui](https://github.com/nathanpeck/clui#gaugevalue-maxvalue-gaugewidth-dangerzone-suffix). I haven't myself but it looks like they could..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is with [ANSII Escape Sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). It's tedious to do manually so I went with a library called [blessed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blessed). It allows you to create terminal user interfaces pretty easily. It takes care of doing all the annoying low-level ANSII escape sequences for you and just gives you controls you can instantiate and configure.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do CLS and then resend new data to the screen ?

Comment: That would clear my entire terminal buffer. Notice when I kill *top* it returns me to my normal prompt and I can see my terminal history, just not the output from *top*. Also notice that while *top* is running I can't see my terminal history.